# IE8 makes my xml corrupt

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer, blueimp

I am using the blueimp fileupload to upload multiple files to my server. In the "done" callback i catch my xml result but is all messed up in IE8. This is the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item type="Struct">
 <item name="data" type="Struct">
  -
  <item name="files" type="Array">
     <item type="Struct">
        <item name="uid">1ixXDSUJiKhwEEUV4NJFoJyxp</item>
        <item name="reference">files[]</item>
     </item>
  </item>
  </item>
   <item name="message" />
  <item name="errorcode">0</item>
 </item>
```

As you can see, it added "-" signs between the xml nodes, and there are not there in chrome or firefox. Is there anyone who can tell me why this happens? Is this a know inssue with IE?

Comment: Isn't that the way IE *renders* the XML? Perhaps you want to see the page *source* :-?

Comment: this is just a return from an ajax call so i dont really have a page source for it

Comment: Then, where and how do you see the code?

Comment: IE uses a fake document when it loads an XML into an iframe to make the xml 'pretty'. You can get the real XML from its XMLDocument property.

Comment: Thats just the problem, the return is allready bad, causing the fial handler of the fileupload to be triggered instead of the done. I could return it as string and put it in a variable but i have no idea how to convert it to xml afterwards.